# What does 「フトアゴヒゲ」mean in 「フトアゴヒゲトカゲ」("Central Bearded Dragon​" lizard)?

Tags: meaning, words, etymology, definitions, animals

I'm guessing ヒゲ means hair, which makes sense since the lizard has "bearded" in its name. Not sure about the rest of the フトアゴ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

フトアゴヒゲ is for [太]{ふと}い[顎髭]{あごひげ}. It refers to the thick beard-like spines of the lizard.